# changing the index value of vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

How do I change the index values of a vector/array in MATLAB?
For example, `A = [1 2 3 4 5]`. Here `A(1) = 1`, `A(2) = 2` and so on. I want to change the base value of the index to say `1001` or `2001` so that now `A(1001) = 1` or `A(2001) = 1`.

Can someone please tell me how it can be done in MATLAB. Appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't really do that without padding your vector... can you explain why you want to do this? What is your end goal? There may be a better way forward

Comment: I have N studies which each yield a unique value. Just wanted the index to relate to the Study ID or study number so that I can use the find function for future work

Comment: Rather maintain a separate vector of the study matrices. You can't just change how matlab indexes

Comment: Ya that was the way I was leaning towards. Just needed to know this was a dead end. Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: @VigneshR you can store each study in a different cell in a cell array. Or you can use `struct` with a field for each study (allows you to name the study).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that really but you could 'spoof' it using a `sparse` matrix perhaps (depending strongly on what your application is):

```
b(1001:1005) = sparse(A)
```

However for what you've mentioned in your comments it makes much more sense to do something like this:

```
study = 1001:1005;
results = 1:5;  %// This is your A

ind = A == 3;

%// Now find the study number that matches your specific result:
study(ind)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly change the indexing of the arrays in Matlab, but you can use a helper anonymous function to convert your `study ID` to the proper index.

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5] ;
sid = @(ix) ix-1000 ;
```

Now `sid` (short for *studyID* but you can name it what you like) will always remove `1000` to whatever index you throw at it. It works for a single index:

```
>> A(sid(1002))
ans =
     2
```

But also for multiple indices:

```
>> A(sid([1001 1003:1004]))
ans =
     1     3     4
```

Comment: Good `anonymous_function` usage to "translate" the coordinates, +1.